# Dependency injection cannot be handled using php-di

Tags: php, dependency-injection, autoload, php-di

This is a problem that drove me crazy for over one week. I installed [php-di](http://php-di.org/) via composer and added my own project to the composer.json file:

```
{
    "name": "mypackage/platform",
    "description": "MyPackage Platform",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php-di/php-di": "^6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "MyPackage\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Then I created mine /public/index.php:

```
<?php
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use function DI\create;
use MyPackage\Base\Service;

$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
$containerBuilder->useAutowiring(false);
$containerBuilder->useAnnotations(false);

$containerBuilder->addDefinitions([
    Service::class => create(Service::class)
]);

$container = $containerBuilder->build();

$service = $container->get('Service');
$service->showMessage();
```

And this is /src/Base/Service.php content:

```
<?php

namespace MyPackage\Base;

class Service
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function showMessage()
    {
        echo "<BR>Inside Service";
    }
}
```

When I troy to load index.php, Apache says:

```
[Thu Dec 05 18:57:47 2019] [error] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught DI\\NotFoundException: No entry or class found for 'Service' in /var/www/html/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Container.php:135
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/public/index.php(22): DI\\Container->get('Service')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /var/www/html/vendor/php-di/php-di/src/Container.php on line 135
```

Whats is wrong with my approach?

Answer (score 0):

`$container->get('Service')` asks the container for the entry `'Service'`. This is a string. There is no namespace.

In your configuration, you configured the service under the `Service::class` key: `Service::class` returns the full class name, which is `MyPackage\Base\Service`.

So the error is: you have the service under `MyPackage\Base\Service`, and you try to fetch it via the key `Service`.

Comment: Thank you Matt, what do you recommend (is the best practice) here? I used $container->get(Service::class);, and still does not work.

Comment: This is probably because you did not import the class name. I recommend you read about namespaces in PHP, and experiment with class names to learn more about it. This is something to learn that is outside of the topic of PHP-DI itself.